# Suspicious connections in Apache access log

Tags: apache-2.4

I recently bought a VPS to run some basic websites on, and today I was checking the access and error logs of Apache and I noticed some strange connections in the access log.

Here are two examples:

```
XXX.XXX.XX.XXX - - [27/Jul/2019:06:39:54 +0000] "CONNECT i.instagram.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 403 168 "-" "-"

XXX.XX.XX.XX - - [27/Jul/2019:08:35:10 +0000] "\x03" 400 0 "-" "-"
```

The second of the two IP addresses (that I have hidden) has been reported in multiple places for things like spam and malicious activity.

The VPS is pre-configured to run the LAMP stack, so I assume I have nothing to worry about. But I cannot find anything on the internet in relation to these logs, so wanted to check that things like this are expected to happen when a VPS is exposed to the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> check that things like this are expected to happen when a VPS is
>   exposed to the internet.

Yes, constant scans and malicious garbage is the norm on the Internet.

> VPS is pre-configured to run the LAMP stack, so I assume I have
>   nothing to worry about

False, choosing a particular platform does not make you secure. Failed request noise is not of concern, no. However, web apps do have vulnerabilities and they are exploited. Apply security updates and keep reviewing logs.